# How to perform complex time window queries in CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

I'm trying to work with my time-series data using CnosDB, but I'm facing difficulties when executing complex time window queries. I want to calculate a rolling average of a certain metric within a specific time range, or find the maximum value within a given time window. I'm currently using [Name of your time-series database], but I'm unsure how to achieve these operations within it.

I've attempted some basic queries, such as selecting data within a specific time range, but I'm unsure how to apply aggregate functions to get the results I'm looking for.

I'm hoping to learn how to perform operations like rolling averages, finding maximum values within time windows, and similar complex operations within a time-series database.